# quadratic system of three equations with three unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

If $x,y,z$ are real and positive and they verify the system
$$\begin{cases}
x^2+xy+y^2=36\\
y^2+yz+z^2=64\\
z^2+zx+x^2=100
\end{cases}$$
Find the value of the sum $S=xy+yz+zx$

Of course I tried the obvious, to sum them all up, to bring each equation to the canonical form, to guess. I can see that the system is symmetric, but I don't know how does it help. Someone who already solved it told me that $S$ is proportional to $\sqrt{3}$. How to proceed?

Comment: I fed the set to Alpha and the result is a mess.  It found four solutions.  You must be expected to find $S$ without solving the set

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643121/find-xyyzzx-given-systems-of-three-homogenous-quadratic-equations-for-x-y/2643593#2643593

Comment: You can eliminate $y,z$ to obtain an equation in $x$

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, you're right.  I've worked out the exact value of $S$ thanks to your comment.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, it's not needed.  In fact, we have a more elegant solution using [tag:geometry] of [tag:triangle] with solving any variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use Wolfram Mathematica then the answer
comes out as

```
In[1]:= (x y+y z+z x)^2 /. Solve[{x^2+x y+y^2 == 36,
     y^2+y z+z^2 == 64, z^2+z x+x^2 == 100}] //
     Simplify //Sqrt //InputForm
Out[1]//InputForm=
     32*Sqrt[3], 32*Sqrt[3], 32*Sqrt[3], 32*Sqrt[3]}
```

and so the answer is $\;32\sqrt{3}.$

Alternatively, define

$$ q_1 := x^2+xy+y^2,\; q_2 := y^2+yz+z^2,\; q_3 := z^2+zx+x^2 $$

and also let

$$ e_1 := x+y+z,\; e_2 := xy+yz+zx,\; e_3 := xyz. $$
Given that
$\;q_1=36, q_2=64, q_3=100,\;$ then
$\;q_1+q_2+q_3 = 2e_1^2-3e_2 = 200\;$ and $\;q_1q_2+q_2q_3+q_3q_1 = e_1^4 + 3e_2^2 -3e_2e_1^2 = 12304.\;$ Now from the first equation $\;e_2=(2e_1^2-200)/3\;$ and when substituted into the second equation gives
$\;(40000-200e_1^2+e_1^4)/3 = 12304\;$ with solution $\;e_1^2 = 100+48\sqrt{3},\;$ and now $\;e_2 = 32\sqrt{3}.$

Answer (score 4):

(Solution edited to give a value of $S$.)

1. By the Cosine Law of [triangle](/questions/tagged/triangle), $x^2+y^2-2xy(\cos 120°) = 6^2$, so an obtuse triangle of side lengths $x,y,6$ with internal angle $120°$ facing the longest side with length $6$ is formed.  Idem for the other two inequalities.
2. Observe that a triangle with lengths $6$-$8$-$10$ is a right-angled triangle.  (Denoted $\triangle ABC$.)
   [image]
   For each of the given equation, one of the smaller arcs $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}} \arc{AB},\arc{BC},\arc{CA}$ represents the locus of the vertex with the largest angle of the corresponding obtuse triangle.
3. It's well known in [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry) that these three arcs coïncide at the [Fermat point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point) $F$ of $\triangle ABC$.  Since $\triangle ABC$ contains no internal angle larger than $120°$, $F$ lies inside $\triangle ABC$.
4. *No* need to solve for the variables $x,y,z$.  (represented by $AF, BF, CF$) Use a property of the Fermat point that the angles formed by $AF, BF, CF$ are $120°$.
   \begin{align}
   \text{Area of } \triangle ABC &= \text{Area of } \triangle ABF + \text{Area of } \triangle BCF + \text{Area of } \triangle ACF \\
   \frac{6 \times 8}{2} &= \frac12 xy (\sin 120°) + \frac12 yz (\sin 120°) + \frac12 zx (\sin 120°) \\
   24 &= \frac{\sqrt3}{4} (xy+yz+zx) \\
   S &= 32 \sqrt 3
   \end{align}

Comment: Quite impressive. Thank you! I was looking though for sth more algebraic!

Comment: @asd11 Thanks for upvote and comment.  I understand this. 
 However, if you're lucky enough, a geometrical solution can be are more elegant and elementary than an analytical one (using algebra and/or multivariable calculus), so as minimizing the sum of distances of some geometrical figure.

Comment: Would you mind it to share which software you used to draw that beautiful image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @XavierStuvw Sorry for my late response.  I used a relevant image from Wiki to save time.  In the picture $\triangle ABC$ isn't a right-angled, but it should be from my answer.  I believe that the author of this good-looking picture used TikZ, which is quite time-consuming to learn, but the resulting images would look impressive.  I'm taking an indefinite break from this site to learn more SVG.